# How can I reduce function calls in higher order functions when query

Tags: clickhouse

our online clickhouse, we have many  higher order functions have a same func parameter.

Such as:

```sql
with groupArray(station_id) as station_list, 
     groupArray(sta_lng) as lng_list, 
     groupArray(sta_lat) as lat_list 
select arrayFirst((x,y)->(y=460642), lng_list,station_list), 
       arrayFirst((x,y)->(y=460642), lat_list,station_list) 
from table_test
```

have the same func:(x,y)->(y=460642) and param: station_list.
so whether we can reduce the same func calls to improve the query performance.

And have 2 ideas about this.

one is use the arrayFirstIndex().
whether can use this to improve the performance.
Such as

```sql
with groupArray(station_id) as station_list, 
     groupArray(sta_lng) as lng_list, 
     groupArray(sta_lat) as lat_list, 
     arrayFirstIndex((x)->(x=460642), station_list) as idx 
select lng_list[idx], lat_list[idx] from table_test
```

another is creating table function to return all data, and get the needed data from this table.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference. CH evaluates the same expression only once.

And you can use aliases (some_expression as ALIAS)

And you can use indexOf

```sql
with groupArray(station_id) as station_list, 
     groupArray(sta_lng) as lng_list, 
     groupArray(sta_lat) as lat_list
select lng_list[( indexOf(station_list, 460642) as idx )], 
       lat_list[idx] from table_test
```

You can use Tuples

```sql
with groupArray(station_id) as station_list, 
     groupArray( (sta_lng, sta_lat) ) as lng_lat_list
select (lng_lat_list[indexOf(station_list, 460642)] lng_lat).1 as lng,
       lng_lat.2 lat
from table_test
```